# Can i use apache mahout with django application

Tags: python, django, apache, mahout

I am building the web application in python/django.

I need to apply some machine learning algorithms on some data. I know there are libraries available for python. But someone in my company was saying that Mahout is very good toll for that.

i want to know that can i use it with python/django. or i should do that with python libraries only

Comment: Does this help? http://bayesianbrain.blogspot.in/2011/03/mahout-and-python-integration-using.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you could build an independent application with mahout, and you python application is just a client.